# no Swedish characters when PHP writes localized names of days

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am developing a Wordpress site. Its character set is UTF8 and language/locale is `en_GB`. When I use Swedish characters åäö in the Wordpress editor they are rendered alright. But I have done some tweaking to how dates and days are displayed so that they display Swedish names for days and months, like so:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        // define variables
        $date = get_field( 'event_date' ); //event_date is a string value
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);
        $tid = get_field( 'tid' );

        // write the html 
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'swedish');
        echo strftime( '%A %d %B %Y', $timestamp ) ;
        echo '<div>' . $tid . '</div>';

    }
```

However, when PHP writes the Swedish days the special characters get messed up: "söndag" becomes "s�ndag". This happens both on WAMP and on the live server.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't PHP output the Swedish days correctly?

Comment: It can. You probably need to change the text encoding of your PHP source file from iso-8859-1 to utf-8.

Comment: I am not sure how to change the encoding of the php source files. I am using Brackets (on Windows) so I though that meant they were already encoded as UTF8? Meanwhile, I added this to the index.php in the wordpress root: `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1'); ?>` It solves the problem on the live site but not locally in WAMP, guess I can live with that. However, is it a backwards way of solving the issue?

Comment: You're right — brackets should be using UTF-8 by default. I guess that means the call to `strftime()` is using the wrong character encoding. Try adding `define("CHARSET", "utf-8");` after the `setlocale()` call. Better still, go through your php.ini file and make sure the character encoding and locale are set correctly in there.